# Assign p-values to all data point in the population in order to demonstrate some of them are not normal

Tags: r, statistical-significance, data-visualization, p-value

a very naive question for some of you. I have a population of 80000 data points. Some points in the population are many SD away from the rest of the population and they could be easily identified and visualized assigning them a p-value. I know that excluding those values, the population follow a nice normal distribution. What I ask you today is whether you can suggest me an approach to assigning a pvalue to each data point in the population where the null hypothesis is that the data contribute to the normality.

Comment: Individual points can't be "skewed".  And with 80000 it wouldn't be unusual to see observations more than 5 standard deviations away from the mean.  Are you sure you want to do this?  Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: Hi Dason, thank you for your comment. I think it is good to highlight the points (they are 2000)  which completely differ from the rest of the population. For sure people will ask the significance of my observation and giving a pvalue to each single point will do the job. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can assign cohen's d to each value and determine if it is close or not based on that. Cohen's d is more appropriate because it is a measure of pointwise distance from a point or continuum.

Comment: I don't know what "the data contribute to the normality" means in a precise sense, and I don't know [why](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl) you want to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, just to explain, let's imagine I have a population of 80000 people of which 78000 are 1.70m +- 0.2m tall and the other 2000 are 1.9m+- 0.5 tall. Assigning a pvalue to each data point where the null hypothesis is: it is normal, would highlight the difference between the data and the people which will review the paper will filter data points base on the pval.

Comment: In your example, isn't in the case that all 82,000 datapoints are drawn from a normal distribution? It's just that 80,000 datapoints are drawn from one normal distribution and the remainder are drawn from another. But I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: My advice is to think about how the data are being generated. Are there two or more different ways of generating data, one of which is a normal distribution, and another (or multiple others) which is different? (Different meaning normal but with different parameters or not normal.) If so then what you expect to see in the observed data is a so-called mixture distribution. Parameters for mixture distributions can be estimated by an expectation-maximization (EM) algorithm.

Comment: Your posted question is not clear. Please include information from your comment, and explain more about what you're trying to achieve here (the underlying issue).

Comment: The underlying issue is giving pvalue to all the data points of a distribution in which the null hypothesis is "it is normal".I need to do this in order to give significance to data which are not under the normality because it will be required by the reviewer of my paper.